# Retrieve multiple hand-chosen points from data cursor mode

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Dear stackoverflow community,

I'm currently working on programming a car sharing simulator for a thesis. However, a car sharing network consists of various car sharing stations that consequently have coordinates which can be derived from a city map. Since varying the number of stations is a must-have feature of my simulator and adding stations therefore is a compulsory, I searched for a method of retrieving position data from the data cursor mode. Luckily, there were some hard-working programmers before me, whose efforts I used:

```
statDiff = length(statCoords)- length(defaultstatCoords);
hf5 = figure(5);
set(0,'CurrentFigure',hf5)
[B, map] = imread('Hannoverosm.png');
C = imresize(B, 0.975);
imshow(C, map)
dcmObject = datacursormode;
pause
datacursormode off
cursor = getCursorInfo(dcmObject);
newStat = [cursor.Position(1), cursor.Position(2)].';
defaultstatCoords(:,end + 1) = newStat;
statCoords = defaultstatCoords;
```

(whereas cursor.Position(1) is the x and cursor.Position(2) is the y position)

I'm now stuck on writing a loop which allows me not only to add one station (at the moment the data cursor modes closes after adding one station), as in the current solution, but to retrieve as many points (aka new station coordinates) as the difference between the default number of stations and the desired nr. of stations. Imagine: I have 5 default stations and I want 10 stations in total. The difference between both would be 5, thus I would need to hand pick/click 5 points that would become the coordinates of the five new stations.

p.s: for a better understanding, look at the enclosed picture that shows the current status.

[image: blah]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would use `ginput` and use a `while` loop until you decide to push a sentinel key... like ENTER or ESCAPE.   Or, what you can do is loop through as many times as you have points.  I'll write you an answer.

Comment: That is pretty nice, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  I have just written an answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) and specify how many points you want to click in your image.  This will then return arrays of x and y co-ordinates that specify those co-ordinates that you clicked in your image.  Note that these will be returned as **column vectors**.  Without further ado, do this:

```
%// Your code from before
statDiff = length(statCoords)- length(defaultstatCoords);
hf5 = figure(5);
set(0,'CurrentFigure',hf5)
[B, map] = imread('Hannoverosm.png');
C = imresize(B, 0.975);
imshow(C, map);

%// New
[X,Y] = ginput(statsDiff); 

%// Transpose the results to make them row vectors
%// X and Y are column vectors from the output of ginput
X = X.';
Y = Y.';

% // Add to array
defaultstatCoords = [defaultstatCoords [X; Y]];

%// Assign back
statCoords = defaultstatCoords;
```

---

What the above code will do is spawn your image like you had before.  When you encounter `ginput`, focus will be placed on your image, and you are allowed to click anywhere you want on the image up until `statsDiff` times.  When you are finished, the `X` and `Y` co-ordinates will be placed in the `X` and `Y` variables.  `X` is assumed to be horizontal while `Y` is assumed to be vertical.  Also, the origin is at the top left corner.

Looking at how you are constructing where you are placing your points, I am assuming that the first row contains all of your `X` points while the second row contains all of your `Y` points.  As such, I extend your `defaultstatCoords` array so that the first row is extended to have these new `X` points, while the second row is extended to have these new `Y` points.  I then assign these back to `statCoords` for your purposes.

One small note is that `ginput` does not display the X and Y co-ordinates on the screen as in data cursor mode.  As such, the only way you can see which points you have clicked is when `ginput` exits.

---

However, if you really want to use the data cursor mode, you could encapsulate this in a loop like so:

```
for count = 1 : statsDiff
    dcmObject = datacursormode;
    pause
    datacursormode off
    cursor = getCursorInfo(dcmObject);
    newStat = [cursor.Position(1), cursor.Position(2)].';
    defaultstatCoords(:,end + 1) = newStat;
end 
statCoords = defaultstatCoords;
```

The problem with this approach is that once you choose your point, you have to push <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then click on the window again and choose the next point.  This will certainly do what you accomplished, but it is annoying to constantly go back and forth between the MATLAB command prompt and the figure window.  However, this method is good in that you can drag your mouse around and choose a point.  When you're finally ready, you then push <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  With `ginput`, a mouse click assumes that this is the final point that you want to choose, and thus proceeds to choosing the next point.

It depends on what you want to do, but either method should work.

---

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I'll try it asap, thanks for your efforts! +1 for you and if it works (and I sure as hell suppose it does!) I'll accept your answer :) Have a nice evening!

Comment: @Atlan - I've also provided a solution using data cursor mode.  However, I would recommend that `ginput` method as it is faster... but if you want accuracy, then use the data cursor mode.  You were right in encompassing the method in a `for` loop.  I just put in some extra logic to make it work.  That solution can be found at the end of my post.  Either one should work.  Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! I'm always stunned about the willingness of stack overflow users to help others :)

Comment: It worked out quite perfectly, although I prefered the second solution, since it was easily implemented. However, I'll try the first solution tomorrow, as it's more convenient for the user :)

Comment: @Atlan cool! Glad it worked. I always like helping others here. I used to teach at my university so this is just paying it forward. It also keeps me sharp too! Let me know how it goes but I'm glad the second method worked.

Comment: Although the station adding feature is far better now, it still lacks an important function. Right now, the user is forced to blindly pick spots around the map, as he can't see the default stat coords. Therefore, I need to plot these stations so that the user can see them while the data cursor mode is running. However, when I try to plot them, I either see solely the stations (without the underlying map) or the map without anything on it. I'm pretty confused about it. See the following code:

Comment: Nvm, solved it myself! Just needed hold on/hold off :)